# Restrict parameter type

Tags: f#

I am trying to create a bit more compact calling convention for a condition checking engine. Working example code is:

```
type MyType(s:string, i:int) =
    member val s = s with get, set
    member val i = i with get, set

let StringLenAtLeast10 =
    fun (s:string) -> s.Length >= 10  

let IntAtLeast10 =
    fun (i:int) -> i >= 10

let SelectS =
    fun (f:MyType) -> f.s

let SelectI =
    fun (f:MyType) -> f.i

type Condition1<'a>(f:'a->bool) =
    member this.IsSatisfied obj = f obj

let cond11 = new Condition1<MyType>(fun f -> StringLenAtLeast10 (SelectS f))
let cond12 = new Condition1<MyType>(fun f -> IntAtLeast10 (SelectI f))
```

I wanted to improve it a bit by restricting the parameters intermediate type like this:

```
type Condition2<'a>(selector:'a -> 'b, f:'b->bool) =
    member this.IsSatisfied obj = f (selector obj)

let cond21 = new Condition2<MyType>(SelectS, StringLenAtLeast10)
let cond22 = new Condition2<MyType>(SelectI, IntAtLeast10)
```

It does however not work, probably for obvious reasons. I am trying to, a. improve the calling conventions, is it possible, and b. find out why it's unable to figure out the type relations?

/Edit:
As pointed out by kvb, all type parameters must be explicitly specified. That just have the problem of not being able to group conditions with different type parameters in a list. So instead, I took advantage of the type system like this:

```
type Condition<'a>(selector, checker) =
    member this.IsSatisfied (obj:'a) = (checker (selector obj)):bool
```

and type inteference will not allow one to use a condition like this

```
let cond = new Condition<MyType>(SelectS, IntAtLeast10)
```

because it knows that the output of SelectS is not an accepted input to IntAtLeast10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of a type's type parameters must be explicit in its definition, so you need to do:

```
type Condition2<'a, 'b>(...) = ...
```

At the call site you can omit the `new` keyword and the explicit parameters and they'll usually be inferred:

```
let cond21 = Condition2(SelectS, StringLenAtLeast10)
```

Comment: While this works, I cannot group the conditions in a list because the type signatures are different. I have found a relatively simple solution that I will update the post with later today.

I have accepted your answer because it pointed me in the right direction.